# Launch MonoTouch iPhone App with Custom Url/Protocol?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to register a custom Url scheme or Protocol, like myapp:123, with MonoTouch? I'd like my MonoTouch app to launch when the user clicks this link in a web page, mail or calendar description, and pick upp the url "parameters", in this case "123".

In short I want the same functionality as for the Spotify app in iPhone with its spotify:track:123123 Can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I've done it in a couple of my MonoTouch applications.  It is actually required when you use the Facebook SDK for logging into your app.

In general, follow the same instructions you would for a regular Objective-C app: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html  (look under "Communicating with other apps")

In your `AppDelegate` there is a `HandleOpenURL` method to override.  Beyond that there are just some settings in your Info.plist to change.

Comment: Yep! Got it working. Easier than I thought actually :) Edited the Info.plist manually to get the right stuff in there about the scheme, then implemented HandleOpenUrl() in AppDelegate and that was it!

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is and here's what you need to do.

Add in Info.Plist the following somewhere within the dict tags:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.companyname.com.receiver</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myapp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Then in AppDelegate.cs override the `HandleOpenURL` method:

```
public override bool HandleOpenURL (UIApplication application, NSUrl url)
{
    if (url == null) {
        return false;
    }

    var uri = new Uri(url.ToString()); // I prefer working with the Uri class.

    // Your logic here

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code mate, it will help others. I had read somewhere that the support for this was removed in the current version of monotouch, but it seems to work just perfect :)